# How to launch 3rd party external application from my own WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, process, nvidia, interprocess

I have wpf application. I need to be able to launch 3rd party external application from my wpf app.
I have searched and found I can use `Process.Start()` but for that i need the path to 3rd party external applications executable.

Would I be able to get the path for 3rd party external applications executable from my wpf application code?

OR 
Is there any process to launch existing apps in windows from wpf application ?

Ex: I need to launch Nvidia GeForce Experience from my wpf application on button click

Answer (score 1):

To know the path of external apps - I can think of 3 ways:

1. Look at the known Registry Keys for your external apps (like Nvidia
   wil lalways make a specific entry and also puts the Install Path and
   at times the path to exe)
2. Assume the user would install at the default location: C:\Program Files - so search in it for the executable
3. Ask user to do a one time setup by browsing the executable. That way your wpf app can launch it any other time.